# Download some portion of data (Blackberry)

Tags: web-services, blackberry, java-me

I've been trying to download some file through a web service and its perfectly downloaded, but now I'm trying to add a feature if the file wasn't downloaded completely, the app should download only the remaining byte array and append to the existing one, using

```
connection = (HttpConnection) cf.getConnection(_url).getConnection();
int alreadyDownloaded = 0;

if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
      inputStream = new DataInputStream(connection.openInputStream());
      final int len = (int) connection.getLength();
      if (len > 0) {
         String filename = _url.substring(_url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
         FileConnection outputFile = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path + filename, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);

         if (!outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.create();
         } else {
            alreadyDownloaded = (int) outputFile.fileSize();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + alreadyDownloaded + "-");
         }
```

And at this line

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + alreadyDownloaded + "-");
```

I get an exception that says

> Stream not in setup state

How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling this line

```java
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + alreadyDownloaded + "-");
```

**after** you have already opened the connection, and sent the request parameters.  So, it's too late to now change the `Range` property.

From [BlackBerry API docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html):

> After an output stream has been opened by the openOutputStream or
>   openDataOutputStream methods, attempts to change the request
>   parameters via setRequestMethod or the setRequestProperty are ignored.
>   **Once the request parameters have been sent, these methods will throw
>   an IOException.**

If you look further down in that document, they show an example, which explains a little more:

```java
        // Getting the response code will open the connection,
        // send the request, and read the HTTP response headers.
        // The headers are stored until requested.
        rc = c.getResponseCode();
```

So, you just need to call `setRequestProperty()` **before** this line:

```java
if(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
```